# I want to use Url.Action with Knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am new to knockout and I am having trouble getting the syntax right when using it with MVC markup.

For example this code here;

```
<a href="text.Answer" target="_blank">
    <span style="display:inline-block">
        <img src="@Url.Action("GetPhotoThumbnail", new { path = text.Answer, width = 120, height = 80 })" alt="Property Image" style="margin-top: 5px;" />
    </span>
</a>
```

EDIT
So "Answer" is in the ViewModel and in knockout you would type data-bind="text:Answer" but here I have put in 2 places text.Answer. How do I replace text.Answer in the above code with the correct Knockout markup?

I know the above code will not work but this is a simplified way of showing the problem. I want to data-bind to text.Answer. What is the correct syntax for doing that?

Comment: You need to describe your problem in more detail. There are no knockout-specific with your code.. Was is the problem?

Comment: I have edited the question. I hope it makes more sense now?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've got a view model binded to this part of the DOM, so you should be able to use the `data-bind` attribute and the `attr` binding to achieve the following:

```
<a href="" data-bind="attr : { href: text.Answer } " target="_blank">
    <span style="display:inline-block">
        <img src="@Url.Action("GetPhotoThumbnail", new { path = text.Answer, width = 120, height = 80 })" alt="Property Image" style="margin-top: 5px;" />
    </span>
</a>
```

See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html for more details on this binding.

Also you'll need to make the view model generate you the `img[src]` attribute value so try something like:

```
<img data-bind="attr:{ src: text.answerImgSrc() } " alt="Property Image" style="margin-top: 5px;" />
```

Comment: You guess correctly. I have see my question is not clear so I edited it. You have answered for the hyperlink and that looks good. text.Answer is also within the Url.Action command as well. I would be very grateful if you could fix that as well.

Comment: updated answer, you should generate your img src within the viewmodel now, as this will have more to a client side concern.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly that your `text.Answer` is something bind in client side.

You can't mix `@Url.Action` with client side variables

Try creating your `URL` like this

`"@Url.Action("GetPhotoThumbnail")?path="+variable1+"&width="+variable2+"&height=" +variable3`

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the values you need into the ViewModel.

```
<div id="test">
    <a href="#" data-bind="attr: { href: href }" target="_blank">
        <span style="display:inline-block">
            <img src="" data-bind="attr: { src: imageUrl }" alt="Property Image" style="margin-top: 5px;" />
        </span>
    </a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyViewModel(defaultValues) {
        this.href = defaultValues.href;
        this.imageUrl = defaltValues.imageUrl
    }

    var viewModel = new MyViewModel({
        imageUrl: '@Url.Action("GetPhotoThumbnail", new { path = text.Answer, width = 120, height = 80 })',
        href: '@Url.Action("Test")'
    });
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('test'));
</script>
```